# Bash Parse Variable Values

Tags: bash

I have a command and it returns 108 set of week/enumeration:

**Command:**

```
impala-shell -B -f query.sql
```

**Results:**

```
20180203        1
20180127        2
20180120        3
...
```

I parsed the results and read the week and enumeration as two variables. However, I have to use a variable `wk` to store intermediate results first:

```
wk="$(impala-shell -B -f query.sql)"
echo "$wk" | while read -r a b; do echo $a--$b; done
```

I tried to avoid using additional variable `wk`:

```
"$(impala-shell -B -f query.sql)" | while read -r a b; do echo $a--$b; done
```

But it returned:

```
...
20160213        104
20160206        105
20160130        106
20160123        107
20160116        108: command not found
```

I understand you can use `wk="$(impala-shell -B -f query.sql)" && echo "$wk" | while read -r a b; do echo $a--$b; done` but that doesn't avoid using a variable in the middle. How to compose a one-liner without using the variable `wk`?

Comment: Do you mean `impala-shell -B -f query.sql | while read -r a b ; do echo $a--$b; done`?

Answer (score 1):

or
`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ impala-shell -B -f query.sql | awk '{print $1"--"$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute commands first (inline) when using special quotes ``

Try this (untested, as i neither have your shell, nor that script):

```
`impala-shell -B -f query.sql` | while read -r a b; do echo $a--$b; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Most elegant answer goes to choroba in the question comments! You just need to remove the quotes!

```
impala-shell -B -f query.sql | while read -r a b ; do echo $a--$b; done
```